# Wordpress - How to get the next post based on a meta key value

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I have a function that runs the below code block, the function takes in an ID which is the current post that Im on. But now I need the next post as well but the next post with the same meta key value.

How do I get the next post based on my meta key value?

```
$post = get_posts([
     'post_type'   => $this->post_type,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'orderBy'     => 'DESC',
     'p'           => $id, // This is the current posts ID
     'meta_query' => [
        [
          'key'     => 'info-brand',
          'compare' => '=',
          'value'   => Meta::get($id, 'info-brand')
        ]
     ]
]);

$nextPost = get_next_post();
td(get_adjacent_post()); // this just dumps the next post in the list of posts and totally disregards my meta query on my post query
```

Comment: I assume you're overriding global $post, in the chance that get_adiacent_post handles it, right?

Comment: Correct, I am overriding the global $post. Im using the themosis framework,

http://framework.themosis.com/

Comment: Ok than I suggest to var_dump() $post before and after your override, in order to check if you're getting the correct data with that get_postS().

Comment: So basically I have a route "my-site/listings/{the-listing}". So **the-listing** is my $post that gives me a nice object of data relating to my query now I simply wanna get the next post after that. If that makes sense

Comment: Check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/can-the-next-prev-post-links-be-ordered-by-menu-order-or-by-a-meta-key I think it should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance but the link It didnt help. Ill keep at it :)